# Rails 3 Establish connection to another database works for just one query

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got two databases: one called db1 and the other one called db2. I've got two models, `School` and `SchoolProd`. I want `SchoolProd` to connect to db2, but to also recognize "schools" as its associated table. I achieve this by doing

```
establish_connection :db2
set_table_name 'schools'
```

When I run the rails console, and ask for `SchoolProd.all`, it gives me all objects from the schools table in db2, but when I try `SchoolProd.all` again, it gives me all objects from the schools table in db1, not db2. Why is this happening? The first query I do behaves as expected, but the rest is done in db1. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out why I was getting this error. Turns out I had the `ar-octopus` gem in my Gemfile. This gem provides Database Sharding in ActiveRecord. I decided not to use it, but forgot to remove it from my Gemfile. Once I removed it, everything went fine